# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \ge \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\displaystyle\{a_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ and $\displaystyle\{b_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be two convergent sequences such that $a_n \gt b_n \forall n$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \ge \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$

Is my proof correct?

Proof by contradiction:

As the sequences are convergent, the limits exist. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \bar{a}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \bar{b}$

Assume $\bar{a} \lt \bar{b}$

We know that $\begin{align}\forall\varepsilon \gt 0, \space  \exists N_1\in \mathbb{N}, \space \forall n\gt N_1, |a_n - \bar{a}| \lt \varepsilon \\
\forall\varepsilon \gt 0, \space  \exists N_2\in \mathbb{N}, \space \forall n\gt N_2, |b_n - \bar{b}| \lt \varepsilon \end{align}$

Let $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$

Then, $\forall n \gt N \space |a_n - \bar{a}| \lt \varepsilon, \space |b_n - \bar{b}| \lt \varepsilon$

And, $\begin{align}\bar{a} -\varepsilon \lt a_n \lt \bar{a} + \varepsilon \\
\bar{b} -\varepsilon \lt b_n \lt \bar{b} + \varepsilon \end{align}$

Then $\bar{a} -\varepsilon \lt \bar{b} -\varepsilon \lt a_n \lt b_n \lt \bar{a} +\varepsilon \lt \bar{b} +\varepsilon $ for at least one $n$

Hence we arrive at a contradiction as $a_n \gt b_n \space \forall n$

I'm unsure about the final two steps, but I couldn't think of anything else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to be explicit about the value of $\varepsilon$ you want to use: $\varepsilon = (b - a)/2$ is a good choice.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!